# Getting invalued response why?

Tags: javascript, xml, asp-classic, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Below code in my `request.asp` page

```
<%
    dim http,http_response
    set http = createobject("msxml2.serverxmlhttp")
    http.open "GET", "http://domainname.com/test.asp", 0
    http.send ""
    http_response = http.responsetext
    response.write http_response
%>
```

this is the code in `test.asp` page

```
<%
response.write "<response>test page</response>"
%>
```

This is the response i get when i run `request.asp` page

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="http://domainname.com/?fp=ssl4sm3dbT82UQtwt%2FcElI%2F47tomswsXNyVoSMsfzsty1tUgidK8%2B%2FaJjeRd8ac1FUh%2FcmXV3MNb7AmhC4wlOQ%3D%3D&prvtof=zmVIoXe%2Fdx%2Faywx2PgM4XkFMifEssGS%2BBZ%2Bv8jbeBOk%3D&poru=tssDKxk5smXL0%2FeMnaWALWsu5YRg73QpTvCz8WHAcausUGwak41FGWvF7gnH7iHqUt%2F5cMy5W44y9ULdgKGAlnm9TKvHTUD9BHK09RHSEjP%2FzPHkJ%2Fwrt39XgUfQAyLUF6%2FcBnd3MXRAgR5GfzmUoHuFQmCYJH%2FEUhx1zwtrYNEoPNIwS%2Buj78ykAwnptmxiZW9xt139gcrHTu5VreWbbRnugsEEcQzyzi8GMRMkn5407WGwnrCK2wN8cuXYHNKdku0xjVFftA3HQ%2FjEnghyaUA4qii43c1vBidwn0t2tYfDGtqXXAwNgx%2FfxAJgl9XMW2V9%2BgplVT8jaOZiZMobPfRbqwT1xnab3abkOrvuFy6SB5bJT0KqgkPnxzPFnroPiTeiuKQ83KumBVASvugBWl0llS6qCH5FFcoAwoyVO34%3D&">

</frameset>

<noframes>

    <body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">

    <a href="http://domainname.com/?fp=ssl4sm3dbT82UQtwt%2FcElI%2F47tomswsXNyVoSMsfzsty1tUgidK8%2B%2FaJjeRd8ac1FUh%2FcmXV3MNb7AmhC4wlOQ%3D%3D&prvtof=uKpPMOl34IdXXSlj8gUi7lqY0vikl7iXCpbiTe9pUiQ%3D&poru=rbTj4%2BV%2BmkQH2cvm%2Fv7ahzD9D1YRsSnlfbxP8FyhsbQ9K%2F80EE0py7DsE7W2lWdTJRdJJOcUoO7W1We7VyW7YmRPGJUjz0DT6BNMP%2F86OZXXQzb7%2Foa4QdJ4VRcj4XSPMMw45DSw5PJ7UvSRIYrxV1KHSSUP%2Fgeos7Hjd9ndeKT7%2BO8SA1CJiOxj037xR3ppzX4wMCdJjAt6NlbdpSN4x5bHrLaxs5IUzUPMQPiAl31jA1RwSEKX%2F3JJPp%2FUB3lGOIGqilRliOfjGVoM2Ce5fojLDAH2UX3jOZmsRxiNmFa613TCXGB646iJEtjJwa44E%2FUelIbScYVNaKLGWouSod8Y8Qla%2FDpCZsKID3uu1u6Z0f3VoT89N0g6xowRsje6kvV4BaVdJmPanFb5%2Fc851WQbvCU5u547PneOko8%2BzHs%3D&">Click here to proceed</a>.

    </body>

</noframes>
```

because this response is invalid

I googled the data `?fp=&prvtof=&poru=&` .There are many pages of websites like this. I think it's something like `Wayback Machine - Internet Archive`. But I don't know anything about this.

1. Is it a virus ?
2. Are there settings in iiS7 (I'm using windows 2008 server)?
3. How to solve this?

Comment: When you go to that asp page in the browser what happens?

Comment: Why is this tagged "javascript"? Is that code you whole `request.asp` page?

Comment: Your host or ISP are adding this, talk with their support teams.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it a virus? No, [it's just a service](http://web.archive.org), that scans sites and keeps older versions of that site online. Think of it as a search-engine/bot that passes by every now and then. Just look at the site, it's nothing too evil
2. Are there settings in IIS7? Sure, many... but I think it's possible to register/de-register your site at the aforementioned site (archive thing) so that the crawler doesn't stop by again. Or you can just ignore it.
3. How to Solve this? see above - had a look at the archive's site, too: [here's what you need to do to prevent your site from being crawled](http://archive.org/about/exclude.php)
    a simple robots.txt file that disallows `/`

Comment: i not register my website anywhere... how i can find this?

Comment: @user475464: The link to the site is in my answer, click it and look around. The FAQ section, second question: _"How can I exclude my sites pages"_ is what you need. BTW: you might not have registered your site, that doesn't mean nobody did...